# root.find() not working when called from dictionary- element tree

Tags: python, dictionary, xml-parsing, urllib, elementtree

Im currently using the module element tree & urllib to access/parse and return values from xml files.

Using the root.find/root.findall() methods along with XPath syntax to locate desired info in xml. Then using (.text) to return the value of child/grandchild elements.

When assigning each root.find() to a variable then taking the variable and attaching (.text), i am able to parse and return the value with no issues.

(i.e)

```
x= root.find(./Cameras/Camera/Connected')
print (x.text)

==> True
```

However I would like to place these "root.find()" in a dictionary and call on them later in the script.

(i.e)

```
location= {
    'Cam': "root.find('./Cameras/Camera/Connected')",
    'Mic': "root.findall('./Audio/Input/Connectors/Microphone')",
    'Prod_ID': "root.find('./SystemUnit/ProductPlatform')"
}
```

However, when indexing to dictionary by key and then attempting the add the (.text) i get the following error;

```
y=location['Cam']
print (y.text)

==> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

So this maybe a simple issue im overlooking but do these two methods return the same value? Can the element tree module read root.find() from dictionaries?

Comment: What was your expected output? What if you just `print(y)`?

Comment: that would give me back the value of my key `Cam`
my expected output is to run that value  `root.find('./Cameras/Camera/Connected') ` and parse the xml to return a this specific value in xml so i this instance it would return  `True ` from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting your dictionary values to a literal string.  That is, this:

```
'Cam': "root.find('./Cameras/Camera/Connected')",
```

Is setting the value of key `Cam` to the string value `root.find('./Cameras/Camera/Connected')`. You want to actually call the function and set the key to the return value, so you need to drop the quotes:

```
'Cam': root.find('./Cameras/Camera/Connected'),
```